# Mysql UNIQUE Constraint that only applies if one field has specfic values

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, unique-key

I hope this works somehow:

I have a Mysql Table with 3 column:

```
id = int
state = enum('visible', 'moderated', 'deleted')
user_id = int
```

No user should have more than 1 entry, that is 'visible' or 'moderated', but he can have endless 'deleted' entries.

So, I need a UNIQUE Key on user_id, that only applies if the state is 'visible' or 'moderated'

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two options, first one is fairly simple but would require change in your table structure and application logic.

If you use NULL value instead of 'deleted', you can have as many "deleted" rows as you want for given user_id (having unique constaint on (user_id, state)). Your table structure would be something like this:

```
id = int
state = enum('visible', 'moderated') NULL
user_id = int
```

The other option would involve checking in post update/post insert triggers whether you are not breaking your contraint and throwing "sql exception" vide https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

Comment: NULL is unfortunately no option in my case (because of app design). But I'll look into SIGNALs. Thank you!